# Show that $d:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow[0,\infty[$ is a metric on $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $d:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow[0,\infty[$ be $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
 |x-y|&,\text{if }x,y\neq0\text{ and }x=ty\text{ for some }t\in\mathbb{R}\\
 |x|+|y|&,\text{else.}
 \end{cases}$$
    Show that $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{C}$.

---

So I need to show that (1) $d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$, (2) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ and (3) $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Do the criteria have to satisfy both cases or is it sufficient to show either one? I suppose it's both. Anyways, here is my sorry attempt.

|x-y|:

(1.1): $|x-y|=0 \Leftrightarrow x-y=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$

(2.1): $|x-y|=|-(x-y)|=|y-x|$

(3.1): $|x-z|=|x-y+y-z|\leq|x-y|+|y-z|$

|x|+|y|:

(1.2): $|x|+|y|=0\Leftrightarrow|x|=|y|\Leftrightarrow x=y$

(2.2): $|x|+|y| = |y| + |x|$

(3.2): $|x|+|z| \leq |x|+|y|+|y|+|z| (?)$

Comment: Your proof is incorrect because it wrongly assumes that all three of the expressionss $d(x,z),d(x,y),d(y,z)$ are always either  of one type ($|x-y|$) or else  of the other type ($|x+y|$), and this assumption is unjustified.

Comment: Also, $0 = |x| + |y|$ does not imply $|x| = |y|$. Nor does $|x| = |y|$ imply that $x = y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the criteria have to satisfy both cases or is it sufficient to show either one?

The cases hold for different values of $x$ and $y$. You need to show the criteria for all required values. For a given $x$, and $y$, you have to show it for the criterion those values satisfy. For instance, you start with trying to show $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y$. You do this as follows:

Let $(x, y) \in \Bbb C^2$.

- If $x = y$, then $x = 1\cdot y$, so $d(x,y) = |x - y| = |0| = 0$.
- Suppose $d(x,y) = 0$. If $x = ty$, then $d(x,y) = |x - y| = 0$, so $x - y = 0$ and $x = y$. If $ x \ne ty$, then $0 = |x| + |y|$, so $|x| = -|y|$, but $|x| \ge 0$, and $-|y| \le 0$. Hence the common value can only be $0$. Therefore $x = 0$ and $y = 0$, and so $x = y$. In all cases, $d(x,y) = 0 \implies x = y$.

The other two criteria should be handled similarly. For those it is not enough to just plug "$\iff$" between some statements. You have to actually show that the statements are true for the exact same values of $x$ and $y$.